# Confusion with jQuery, line 1 $not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have just started learning jQuery today, i have written up a code in a javascript file. This code is designed to make a button fade when hovered over it, and then return to normal after moving the mouse away. Now as i have just said, i am very new to jQuery, and that means i am thinking this is down to setting it up wrong. Here is my javascript contents :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttons").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".buttons").fadeTo("fast",0.25);
        });
    $(".buttons").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".buttons").fadeTo("slow",1);
        });
});
```

This javascript file is saying to fade my class "buttons" when i hover over them.. I have linked my HTML file to this js file with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
```

I know that links up to the javascript file correctly, as i open my html and the console says "$ is not defined" on line 1. Now that is the very first line of my javascript. So clearly my html is opening my JS file, but isnt liking the $ on the very first line.

Again, ill repeat, i am very new to this and anything that should be obvious, will not be obvious to me. Thanks for any help i get.

Comment: Make sure you are loading jQuery.js in the line before `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">`, and that the missing `</script>` is also there in both places.

Comment: I'd say you haven't included the jquery libraries :)

Comment: I recommend to follow the jQuery tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: either like everyone says, you haven't included jquery, or it is included but is being assigned to a different namespace than '$' because its in no conflict mode.  If changing every instance of '$' to 'jQuery' makes your script work this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dollar sign belongs to jQuery libraries namespace so you need to include jQuery before using it. After including the library you can use these functions, e.g. for selection via `$('.classname')`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This includes the latest jQuery release in the minified version. You can load and host this file local as well.

Answer (score 2):

Did you include jQuery in your html file? Something like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

This must be included before the first use of $, thus before including your `script.js`

Comment: Works perfectly! Got it, thanks! Thanks also to everyone else providing the right answer

Comment: @DarrylChapman Add that script include on the line before your current script include, so you have both.  You include the jQuery library, and then your script comes after (since it requires jQuery be loaded first).